# How to play sound during phone call from application

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I want to use the same feature in app like VOYPI in iOS.

Playing a background sound during a call.

I have used the below code for playing background sound during call.

Link for the reference app is [here](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/voypi-call-background-sounds/id434826056?mt=8).

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.bgAudioFileName ofType: @"mp3"];    

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath ];

myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

NSError *sessionError = nil;

// Change the default output audio route
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

// get your audio session somehow
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute error:&sessionError];

BOOL success= [audioSession         overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&sessionError];

 [audioSession setActive:YES error:&sessionError];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"error doing outputaudioportoverride - %@", [sessionError    localizedDescription]);
    }
[myAudioPlayer setVolume:1.0f];
[myAudioPlayer play];
}
```

This code will playbackground sound on ongoing carrier call using avaudioplayer.

I have set category AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute.

Using this category receiver will able to listen background sound during ongoing carrier call from app.

But there was one problem with this it will create echo on receiver side.

Help me in this code.

Comment: Hi! did you find a solution for the problem?